# How to call tablet's keyboard with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tablet

I have a question about calling `tablet's keyboard`.

I have a DropDownList and Textbox. And now when I choose DropDownList item I want to set focus on the Textbox and call numeric keyboard. That all have to work without pressing on the Textbox.

I use `ASP.NET MVC` and `jQuery`.

Thank you.

Comment: the user will need to interact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set focus to the textbox to trigger the opening of the keypad, this could help.
Example: http://ftlabs.github.com/fastclick/examples/focus.html
Code: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

and

```
<input type="number">
```

or

```
<input type="tel">
```

to trigger the numeric keypad when the text input receives focus.

Comment: What tablet and OS are we talking about here?

Comment: Your variant calls numeric keyboard when I click on the Textbox. But I want to display keyboard without any action from user's side.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to set focus on the text box onSelect (on the dropdown)

Comment: I've already set focus, but the keyboard question is still open.

Comment: Most tablet OS bring up the keyboard as soon as there is focus on a text field. If this doesn't work, my next attempt would be to invoke the "click" function in jQuery.

Comment: I tried that too. But it didn't work. I've tested on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VJeLY/

```
<select id="dropDownList">
<option>This</option>
<option>That</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="text-inputId"/>​

$('#dropDownList').change(function(){
    $('#text-inputId').focus()
})​
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But it is only set focus. Do you know how can I also call keyboard for a tablet?